# Access UI from another class

Tags: qt4

I have a QLabel used to display status messages in my mainwindow class which handles everything related to the ui. I also have another class that fetches information from a server. I call fetch function from mainwindow. The fetch contains

```
connect(&netMan, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), SLOT(replyFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
```

so when the reply is finished, replyFinished(QNetworkReply *reply) function gets called which handles the reply.

I would prefer a way to update the QLable based on what reply returns. Any suggestions are welcome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ui` pointer which is in mainwindow